# Is it possible for users not to be in passwd?

Tags: command-line, server, users, passwd

So I have a shell on a remote server.

```
    [alexandros.dimos@fep-62-1 ~]$ whoami
    alexandros.dimos
    [alexandros.dimos@fep-62-1 ~]$ cat /etc/passwd
    this too long the point is my user is not there

    [alexandros.dimos@fep-62-1 ~]$ uname -a
    Linux fep-62-1.grid.pub.ro 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 11 13:30:01 CST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From this uname command I can't even understand what kind of linux server it is.

Can someone explain me how is this possible and where can I read more about this kind of server?

EDIT:
the passwd file

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:14:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
gopher:x:13:30:gopher:/var/gopher:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
usbmuxd:x:113:113:usbmuxd user:/:/sbin/nologin
avahi-autoipd:x:170:170:Avahi IPv4LL Stack:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/sbin/nologin
vcsa:x:69:69:virtual console memory owner:/dev:/sbin/nologin
rpc:x:32:32:Rpcbind Daemon:/var/cache/rpcbind:/sbin/nologin
rtkit:x:499:496:RealtimeKit:/proc:/sbin/nologin
saslauth:x:498:76:"Saslauthd user":/var/empty/saslauth:/sbin/nologin
postfix:x:89:89::/var/spool/postfix:/sbin/nologin
ntp:x:38:38::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin
avahi:x:70:70:Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/sbin/nologin
rpcuser:x:29:29:RPC Service User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
nfsnobody:x:65534:65534:Anonymous NFS User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
openvpn:x:497:495:OpenVPN:/etc/openvpn:/sbin/nologin
haldaemon:x:68:68:HAL daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
pulse:x:496:494:PulseAudio System Daemon:/var/run/pulse:/sbin/nologin
gdm:x:42:42::/var/lib/gdm:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
tcpdump:x:72:72::/:/sbin/nologin
razvan:x:500:500:Razvan Dobre:/home/razvan:/bin/bash
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
nagios:x:495:489::/var/spool/nagios:/sbin/nologin
nrpe:x:494:488:NRPE user for the NRPE service:/var/run/nrpe:/sbin/nologin
mapred:x:202:123:Hadoop MapReduce:/tmp:/bin/bash
hdfs:x:201:123:Hadoop HDFS:/tmp:/bin/bash
oprofile:x:16:16:Special user account to be used by OProfile:/home/oprofile:/sbin/nologin
qemu:x:107:107:qemu user:/:/sbin/nologin
dhcpd:x:177:177:DHCP server:/:/sbin/nologin
```

and after

```
[alexandros.dimos@fep-62-1 ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.2 (Carbon)
Release:    6.2
Codename:   Carbon
```

Comment: In `/etc/passwd`, is there anything like `+@groupName`? Also, this is likely a virtualized server running on OpenVZ or something similar.

Comment: Well 1 thing is for sure: it is not Ubuntu so offtopic ;) Just to help out: any respectable linux has an "issue" file (`lsb_release -a` and `/etc/issue`). "fep" is probably front end processor(?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` are not the only places where users can be defined.
These files define only the users which local users.

You can add remote sources of users and groups definition, like :

- an LDAP server
- a NIS/NIS+ server
- a SAMBA or Windows Domain Controller server
- ...

To review all users & groups known by your server, from whatever sources they come, you would preferably use the **getent** command :

```
getent passwd
```

will list all users known by the system, the ones from `/etc/passwd` like the one from remote servers.

For more information about the configuration of users coming from remote servers, I suggest you read any resource about NSS (Name Service Switch) like `man nsswitch.conf` or [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch).

Comment: the getent passwd command shows me the same passwd

Comment: You can try `getent passwd youruser`